# android about Multi-thread process

Tags: android, handle

I have many tasks,and I should use Multi-thread to process them ,what's the best solution,?the mean is I can use The least number of threads but process the most task With the fastest time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `AsyncTask` is useful for you. You can find more about it [Android - AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in this nice explanation and example given.

And if you want to use `Thread` then you have to manage all the threads, and also be sure about `not to blocking the UI Thread.`

**Difference between Handler and AsyncTask...**

1.The Handler is associated with the application's main thread. it handles and schedules
  messages and runnables sent from background threads to the app main thread.

2.AsyncTask provides a simple method to handle background threads in order to update the UI without blocking it by time consuming operations.

The answer is that both can be used to update the UI from background threads, the difference would be in your execution scenario. You may consider using handler it you want to post delayed messages or send messages to the **MessageQueue** in a specific order.

You may consider using AsyncTask if you want to exchange parameters (thus updating UI) between the app main thread and background thread in an easy convinient way.

[Example for Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask in Android](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at services and AsyncTask for thee same. It is better than dealing with pure threads unless you are in NDK and working with pthreads.

Answer (score 0):

A good post on multi-threading in Android can be found here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to do multiThreading in android.

I like to use [handlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) which give you all the tools to lets your UI communicate eeasily with your threads.
For example :

```
public class MyThread extends HandlerThread implements Callback
{
    public MyThread()
    {
        super(ThreadDP.class.getSimpleName(), Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY);
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared()
    {
        super.onLooperPrepared();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case 1 :
                this.doA();
                return true;

            //Message 2 let's call doB()
            case 2 : 
                this.doB();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    //Implement doA() and doB()
}
```

This simple thread can handle message sent by your activity or other threads. The handle system is pretty fast (i can get a 25fps mjpeg without any problem).

There is probably better solution (i'm not an expert) but i can get up to 5 simultaneous thread receiving , sending (and processing) data on network working like a charm.